# Polynomial problem with stickie solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Thank you for all your help, but i cannot solve this problem. Maybe someone help me?

> Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$, $f = aX^4 + bX^3 + cX^2 + dX + e$, $a \neq 0$ with $a$ odd and $a,b,c,d$ in geometric progression with ration $q$ - odd number. 
>   Show that $f$ doesn't have integer zeros.

Comment: What about $e$?

Answer (score 1):

So $$f= a(x^4+qx^3+q^2x^2+q^3x+q^4)$$ and thus $$(x-q)f = a(x^5-q^5)$$ So if $x_0$ is integer zero for $f$, then we have $$x_0^5 = q^5 \implies x_0=q$$

so $$f(x_0) = \underbrace{5aq^4}_{odd}\ne 0$$
A contradiction.